# Unable to send mail (Wordpress and AWS)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Context:

- I am using Amazon Web Services to build and run a Wordpress site.

Issue:

- The problem I have is with sending e-mails from the site. I also installed the plugin "Post SMTP". The error message I am getting is "*Email could not be resent. Error: Unable to send mail. ".*

What I tried so far:

- I reached out to AWS and they wrote me to use Amazon SES service. I have created and configured  an identity on SES. The issue is still there.

I don't know where to look anymore. Can anyone help who faced same or similar issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the phpmail function is working properly. You can use the following code to check it.

```html
<?PHP
$sender = 'someone@somedomain.tld';
$recipient = 'you@yourdomain.tld';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
?>
```

1. Create a php test file using a text editor and save it e.g. as test.php
2. Change the $sender and $recipient in the code.
3. Upload the php file to your webserver.
4. Open the uploaded php file in your browser to execute the php script.
5. The output show either "Message accepted" or "Error: Message not accepted".

If it's showing "Error: Message not accepted"Tell your provider that the standard php "mail()" function returns FALSE.
It's recommended to include the used php test script to show your provider, that the problem is not caused by the php script used.